# Amazon Payments Custom Integration set Seller Order ID

Tags: php, amazon-pay

I have implemented the Custom Integration for "Pay With Amazon" (https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/express/201747030) on PHP. I want to set the seller order id in the end of the checkout flow. The flow is the following

1. User clicks the "Pay With Amazon" button and logs into the Amazon and Click Pay
2. User is redirected to our return page where we are creating the user internally based on Amazon Order Details(GetOrderReferenceDetails) and shows the order summary.
3. User clicks the "Place Order" button which starts order processing, authorize the payment with CaptureNow parameter set true to also Capture the payment amount.

We have available the Internal Order Id only on the STEP 3 and we can't change the sellerOrderId calling SetOrderReferenceDetails because after STEP 1 the Amazon Order is already in "Open" State (not "Draft").

Is there a possibility to have the Amazon Order in "Draft" state after STEP 1 OR is there a possibility to set sellerOrderId after an Order is already in "Open" state ?

Comment: I don't use Express..so when do you (or do you actually manually call) [`ConfirmOrderReference`](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/apireference/201751980)? Though if your internal id is only generated _after_ a _successful_ `Capture`(?) unsure if that will help (vs. generating prior and updating its status accordingly)...

Comment: I am not calling the ConfirmOrderReference because when the user returns again on my site (after he selects the payment method and shipping address on Amazon Payments site) the Order is already confirmed and the order state is already Open.

Comment: Is there a way to tell to the Amazon to let the order in Draft State after the user is returning to my site ?

Comment: Unless corrected by Amazon folk, I don't believe so for **Express Integration**. All of the `paymentAction` [parameters](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/express/201737770) you need to send (default is still `none`) result in confirming the ORO - differing only in how you'd end up Authorizing and Capturing when user is redirected back to your site (they _automatically_ prep it for you - less work, "express").

Comment: You have flexibility in non-Express - e.g. Login and Pay and can call `ConfirmOrderReference` "whenever" you are "ready" - user also doesn't leave your site (really awesome implementation IMHO). However, you still have to confirm prior to doing Auth, so unsure if it will help you...Hth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to update the SellerOrderId after confirming the Order Reference Object (once the ORO is in Open state).

A possible workaround would be to specify the Seller Order ID in the Seller Authorization Note (Passed into the Authorize API call). The value passed into the Seller Authorization Note will then be included in any emails sent by Amazon to the customer.

Comment: I already did this but the site Owner needs to have internal Order ID specified on that page.